# Can I create a generator that returns its length?

Tags: python-3.x

Suppose I create this generator:

```
def first10():
    for i in range(10):
        yield i
```

I want to enable the users of this generator to say "len(first10())" and get "10".

I tried this:

```
first10.__len__ = lambda self: 10
```

but it did not work - I got an error "object of type 'function' has no len()". Is there another solution?

Answer (score 2):

Use a class:

```
class FirstN():
    def __init__(self, n=10):
        self.n = n
    def __len__(self):
        return self.n
    def __iter__(self):
        for i in range(self.n):
            yield i

first10 = FirstN(10)

>>> first10 = FirstN(10)
>>> len(first10)
10
>>> for i in first10:
    print(i)


0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
>>>
```

Note that with this implementation you don't have to call `first10` to iterate over it. If you want to have to call it then use `FirstN()` directly and you can call `len(FirstN())` and iterate over `FirstN()`.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps something like this?

```
from itertools import tee

a = (x for x in range(10))

a, b = tee(a,2)

print(sum([1 for x in b])) 
>>> 10
```

`tee` creates `n` identical iterables, if you create two you can use one to get the length (in any desirable exhaustive or non-exhaustive method) of the other.

Edit:

```
print(len(list(a))
```

Coverts your generator to a list, but now you can check the length using len().

Answer (score 0):

check this

```
>>> def first10():
    for i in range(10):
        yield i
>>> len([i for i in first10()])
10

>>> ([i for i in first10()]).__len__()
10
```

Comment: This solution exhausts the generator. It requires the user to create the generator twice - once to calculate its length and once to use the items.  I want to enable the user to know the length without exhausing the generator.